# Google Analytics and Webmasters Tools for multilingual website

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, google-index, multilingual

This is the first time I am doing a multilingual website and I have a few issues:

I have 3 languages, each in its separated folder: `en/`, `it/`, `ru/`. In the `<head>` section of each one I have `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x" href="http://website.com/x/" />`.
What I don't yet understand is how do I index the website with Google Analytics and Webmasters Tools?

I don't need the ability to see the statistics for each language separated, just the whole website at once. So, given the fact that `http://example.com` automatically redirects to `http://example.com/en/` (default folder/language), do I include the **same** tracking code on each page for all 3 languages? If so, when I register the website to Google Analytics, what URL should I specify is the website? I think `http://example.com` won't work because it automatically redirects to the `en/` subfolder.

And for Webmaster Tools, do I register the root website and then separate it with geolocation, or do I register an account for each of the three languages?

Also, every page has the same name in all three languages. For example:  `http://example.com/en/about-us` in Italian will be `http://example.com/it/about-us`, if this matters somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't need the ability to see the statistics for each language separated, just the whole website at once. So, given the fact that `http://example.com` automatically redirects to `http://example.com/en/` (default folder/language), do I include the same tracking code on each page for all 3 languages?

You should use the same tracking code across all three languages if you want to view the statistics together.  Registering the "site" as `example.com` will work fine in Google Analytics even though that specific URL redirects to the English language directory.

> And for Webmaster Tools, do I register the root website and then separate it with geolocation, or do I register an account for each of the three languages?

You only ever need one "account" for Google Webmaster Tools.  Within an account you can add multiple "sites".   The only reason add the directories as separate "sites" would be to geo-target them.   Since they are language only (and not regional) you don't want to do this.  (Your English site targets worldwide English speakers, not just those in Australia, for example.)  So just add the whole site one time.